# Show that Riemann Theorem does not hold when set is not simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Riemann Theorem states that for any simply-connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ (which is not whole $\mathbb{C}$) there exists biholomorphic map onto the open unit disk.

I find it hard to show that we cannot replace "simply-connected" with "connected". Any ideas?

Comment: Consider the annulus $A = \{z \in \mathbb C \mid \frac{1}{4} < |z| < \frac{3}{4}\}$. What happens if you assume that there is a biholomorphic map from $A$ onto the open unit disk?

Comment: Can you show that anything homeomorphic to a simply connected set must be simply connected?

Comment: Oh, that's you! We got disconnected - DF and I are still wondering what proof of (2) you had in mind in that other thread...

Comment: Hi! I posted comment there but deleted the topic too early i think so you didnt have chance to see it. I was terribly wrong, forgot about one piece of proof. I mean  in showing uniqueness of antiderivative we used CG theorem. It is not needed in showing existence though. Sorry about that. Im complex analysis noob.

Comment: @David here: http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Courses/441-2012/simplyconn.pdf?v2 (page 3). Thanks for claryfing. I had topology a while ago...

Comment: @luka5z No problem. Glad we sorted that out - if there _was_ a proof as you said I wanted to know about it...

Comment: David, If you could - please post your first comment as an answer, so i can mark topic as "answered". Maybe some people will use it in the future. Thanks to both of you!